# How can I assign a literal tab "\t" to a variable and interpret it only when I add it as a delimiter to the sort command?

Tags: bash, sorting, environment-variables, delimiter, csv

I have this command that works:

```
sort -t$'\t' -uk6,6 device_scan.txt
```

But this:

```
d='\t'
sort -t$"$d" -uk6,6 device_scan.txt
```

returns:

```
sort: multi-character tab ‘\\t’
```

The reason for this problem is explained by the fact that in this case:

```
d=$'\t'
echo -n "$d"
```

"d" contains the invisible tab, while in this other case:

```
d=$"\t"
echo -n "$d"
```

"d" contains "\t" literally.

How to solve this problem?

Update 1:

The reason why I can't just assign `d=$'\t'` to the variable to solve the problem is that it is set by less experienced people.

Comment: Note that `$'...'` is unrelated to `$"..."`  - the syntax `$"..."` is there to support locale-specific translations of messages, see [bash manual locale translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation). It's unrelated to interpreting special characters.

Comment: Your "reason" for trying to, incorrectly, use the `$"$d"` syntax is bogus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is to properly assign the variable in the first place.

```
d=$'\t'
sort -t"$d" ...
```

If you want to convert *the string* `\t` to the tab character, use for example `echo -e` or `printf`, or even with variable expansion like so:

```
d='\t'
sort -t"${d//\\t/$'\t'}" ...
sort -t"$(echo -e "$d")" ...  # note - echo is _very_ not portable
sort -t"$(printf "$d")"  ... # be aware of printf formatting strings
```

What I one day discovered is a trick to utilize `awk` variable parsing, which seems to be the best option:

```
 sort -t"$(awk -v var="$d" 'BEGIN{print var}' <&-)" ...
```

And alternatively just write your own parser in your favorite tool that will convert a string with C escape sequences to it's literal meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your tempestive reply. Thanks to you I was able to improve my question a lot, which unfortunately needs to be re-read.

Comment: `What is the right syntax?` To do what? The "right" syntax is closely correlated with intention. `why I can't just assign d=$'\t' to the variable to solve the problem is that it is set by less experienced peopl` As said, you may convert `\t` to tab by using `echo -e` or by using `printf`. Specify your intention - is your intention to support the variable assignment by less experienced people who will type `\t` with the intention of typing a tab? So convert the character.

Comment: It may seem you are asking XY question - you may be not interested in the "right syntax" at all, just in any possible method to convert a string with C escape sequences to it's meaning. (Still your question starts with "how can assign a literal tab to a variable")

Comment: Thank you for the solution `sort -t"$(printf "$d")" -uk6,6 device_scan.txt`. Why this sintax: `sort -t"$(printf "$d")" -uk6,6 device_scan.txt` is better that this sintax?....: `sort -t "$(printf "$d")" -uk6,6 device_scan.txt`

Comment: I see no difference.  You posted same code 3 times, just with a space after `-t`.

Comment: exactly, is better without space? If yes, why?

Comment: There's no difference. It's a personal taste. See [POSIX utility convention](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) and `man getopts` - an optional space is allowed after flags with options.